What is the recommended way to store application-wide values like the path of its AppData folder?
I'm working on a C# application and need to store application-wide values in a MVVM project, such as the path to its AppData folder. What is the recommended approach to achieve this? I'm very new to C#  and not aware of the best practices when it comes to coding.
Things that I've read that I could probably apply?

App.config
Singleton
Dependency Injection


The AppData folder belongs to a user rather than an application. You can use the Environment.SpecialFolder Enum to get any of the standard folders. But you probably need to provide some more details of exactly what problem you are trying to solve here.

I'm not talking about getting the path of the actual app data folder, the thing is I made my own folder within appdata, and I would like to store that path and make it accessible to the whole project, or is that a bad practice?

I would create a class:
   public class MyInfoClass
   {
    private string path1;
    public string Path1 { 
        get {
            if (path1 == null)
            {
                // load my var
                path1="my path";
            }
            return path1;
        }            
        set => path1 = value; }
   }

Register as a Singleton in Program.cs
   builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyInfoClass>();

Then you can inject and access the Path from everywhere in your app.
Although you can Add Eventhandler if a value has changed.
If you want to set the Path1 in Program.cs use:
// Retrieve the value from configuration (assuming "MyInfoClass:Path1" is the configuration key)
string pathValue = _configuration["MyInfoClass:Path1"];

// Register MyInfoClass as a singleton and pass the path value
services.AddSingleton<MyInfoClass>(provider => new MyInfoClass { Path1 = pathValue })

;
Now inject it:
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyInfoClass _myInfo;

    public MyController(MyInfoClass myInfo)
    {
        _myInfo = myInfo;
    }

    // Your controller actions...
}

or in RazorFiles:
@inject MyInfoClass myInfo

